# Thymeleaf access object in outerloop from innerloop

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

i am looping through a list of "roles" , inside each one i loop through a list of "notifications" ( a role can have many notifications )

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-sm-3" th:each="role : ${roles}">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${role.name}"></h5>


                            Notifications :

                            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <th:block th:each="notif : ${notif_list}">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-control-inline">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"
                                            th:id="${notif.id_notif_type}"
                                            th:value="${notif.id_notif_type}" th:field="${role.notifs}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" th:text="${notif.type}"
                                            th:for="${notif.id_notif_type}"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </th:block>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

i want access an object "role" inside the notification loop by using `th:field="${role.notifs}`

here is my Role class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Transactional
public class Role implements Serializable{

public Role() {
}

public Role(Integer id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "roles_notifs", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "notif_id"))
private Set<NotifType> notifs = new HashSet<>();

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<NotifType> getNotifs() {
    return notifs;
}

public void setNotifs(Set<NotifType> notifs) {
    this.notifs = notifs;
}

public void addNotif(NotifType notif) {
    notifs.add(notif);
}

public void removeNotif(NotifType notif) {
    notifs.remove(notif);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Role other = (Role) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

i got an error on `${role.notifs}` , so how can i access the outer object "role" from the inner loop.

i got this error `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'role' available as request attribute`

Comment: Your code shows `<th:block th:each="notif : ${notif_list}">`, shouldn't that be `<th:block th:each="notif : ${role.notif_list}">` ?

Comment: notif_list is a list of all notifications , the purpose is to show all kind of notifications and only those who are associated to role should be shecked.
the code above is an edit html page ( edit role -> notifications relationship )

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the exact error you get with `${role.notifs}` ?

Comment: You can't use generated attributes (like `th:each` variables) as arguments to `th:field` attributes.  If you want too see how to use dynamic fields in forms, see this example: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

Comment: what i want to achieve is : showing all Roles , each one with all available Privileges as checkboxs (those associated to a Role are checked , others not ).